# SSRS Data Labels within created tables/graphs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, label

The SQL database holds gender as 1 and 0 and obviously when I generate a report in SSRS Gender is labelled 1 or 0 in the table/graph.

I would like it to show Male or Female. Can this be done within SSRS?

Or is it best to change the data in the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Instead of referencing the field directly, you can use an `IIf` expression like:

```
=IIf(Fields!gender.Value = 1, "Male", "Female")
```

It might be useful to look at [Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx).